# how to trigger on span element when sorting table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

For sorting a table, based on the size of a file, I use this code:

```
// table sort
    $(document).on('click','th',function() {    
        var table = $(this).parents('table').eq(0)
        var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()))
        this.asc = !this.asc
        if (!this.asc){rows = rows.reverse()}
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){table.append(rows[i])}
    })
    function comparer(index) {
        return function(a, b) {
            var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index)
            return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.toString().localeCompare(valB)
        }
    }
    function getCellValue(row, index){ return $(row).children('td').eq(index).text() }
```

The row with the `td` looks like this:

```
<!-- SIZE-->    
<td class="td-size table-data">
    <!-- raw size for sorting only-->
   <span class="sort-only hide">
          <?php echo filesize($dir . '/' . $file); ?>
      </span>
   <?php                           
     echo sizeFormat(recursive_directory_size($dir . '/' . $file);
   ?>
</td>
```

The value between the `span` element is the raw value (which I want to use for the sort).

How can I trigger on the `span` element inside the `tr` in the javascript? 
Because now it sorts only the value inside the `td`. And it should only be the `span` inside the `td`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps if you adjust your `getCellValue` to check for that `span` it would work:

```
function getCellValue(row, index) { 
    let $td = $(row).children('td').eq(index),
        $span = $td.find('span.sort-only');

    if ($span.length) { // If span.sort-only was found
        return $span.text();
    } 
    else { // If not
        return $td.text();
    };
}
```